# Resizing OOB full screen silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

I'd like to resize my full screen OOB silverlight application based on user preference.

User should be able to resize and keep the full screen application as a widget.

When I try to apply the resize properties, its getting applied to localhost not the Full screen window.

Thanks,

Karthik.

Comment: You want a full screen app to be resized? Sorry but it doesn't make sense. Maybe what you want is a borderless OOB window?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (App.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
{
    App.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
else
{
    App.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
}
```